# I can't install iconv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, iconv

When I run `gem install iconv`, it fails as follows:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing iconv:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/myname/local/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/iconv-1.0.4/ext/iconv
/home/myname/local/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160802-38989-1ie1z24.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_enc_get() in ruby/encoding.h... yes
checking for rb_sys_fail_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I don't know how to fix this.
What should I do?

Comment: Which platform/distribution is this? You seem to be missing a package providing the iconv.h include file.

Comment: I fixed! The two option was needed. --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/include  --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/lib

Answer (score 2):

If your host is running Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo aptitude install libc6-dev
```

if Fedora/Redhat:

```
sudo yum install libc6-devel
```

Then retry with `gem install iconv`. All credits go to @lars-haugseth.

Comment: Doubt that's going to work: "libticonv-dev - Texas Instruments calculators charsets library [development files]"

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 there is no `libiconv-dev` either. My iconv.h is provided by the `libc6-dev` package.

Comment: Indeed. I must’ve needed some rest. Updated an answer accordingly.